# Eclipse Installing Android app on Device Stopped working

Tags: android, eclipse

I updated the SDK tools and now the app wont install to the device any more. I also changed the name of the app

Logcat:

```
[2013-02-25 12:51:11 - TVR] Uploading TVR.apk onto device 'c1607234sdsdf'
[2013-02-25 12:51:11 - TVR] Installing TVR.apk...
[2013-02-25 12:51:13 - TVR] Success!
[2013-02-25 12:51:13 - TVR] /TVR/bin/TVR.apk installed on device
[2013-02-25 12:51:13 - TVR] Done!
```

The app is no where on the device!

As you can see that process happens in like 2 seconds, so its not really doing any thing!

Comment: It is taking 2 seconds (not 0.02 ms), the time is formatted as hours:minutes:seconds

Comment: This is on the actual device, same thing on a adv

Comment: Go to taskmanager or, Settings -> Apps, then look there for the app. Maybe it is not visible somehow on your app-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have updated your Manifest with Intent Filter for Launcher.

Comment: Damn, I must have moved this or something! Thansk